# Jest Mock User Module in All Test Files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

> Is there a way to make it so that jest always mocks my modules so I don't need to include it in all my jest tests?

Currently I have a config file

```
// src/__mocks__/config.js 
export default {
  dbConfig: 'TestDBConfiguration'
};

// src/config.js
export default {
  dbConfig: ... // Some other stuff
};
```

To run my unit tests I have to use the mocked **config.js**.
Currently in all my unit tests I have to include **jest.mock('../config');**

```
// org.test.js
jest.mock('../../config');
import db from '../db';              // This internally uses the config file
import otherFile from '../otherFile'; // This also uses the config file

// Code that calls both db/otherFile
```

Sometimes when I create a test I might forget to include **jest.mock('../config')** which is one of the reasons why I want it included in all my tests.

I've looked into enabling `automock` but it seems to break my tests instead. https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#automock-boolean

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can add `setupFiles` or `setupFilesAfterEnv` into your jest configuration to run before all your tests.

https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array

```
// package.json
...
"jest": {
  "setupFiles": "./src/setupTests.js"
}

// setupTests.js
jest.mock('config'); // Path to config file
```

Comment: Can this be applied only withina subdirectory of files. I have a bunch of tests files that require common mocking, but the rest doesn't.

Comment: I have the same issue as @CMCDragonkai. I have several files which need the exact same module mock, but other files should NOT use this mock. There doesn't seem to be any way to do this other than being forced to boilerplate copy/paste it in these files.

Answer (score 24):

Jest documentation has been updated and uses [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfilesafterenv-array) to run code that can utilize Jest functions like `jest.mock()`.

Updating [@smirky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3263939/smirky)'s example to use `setupFilesAfterEnv`:

```
// package.json
...
"jest": {
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["./src/setupTests.js"]
}
// setupTests.js
jest.mock('config'); // Path to config file
```

On a sidenote, if you wish to `import/require` modules for every test you run, you can use [`setupFiles`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfiles-array).

Comment: This is definitely the better choice in 2023. Especially if you include a test step in your builds. Thanks